# invalid record insertion in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

INSERT INTO `teams`(`team_name`, `tournament_id`, `pool_id`) VALUES ('Anis',"SELECT `tournament_id` FROM `tournaments` WHERE `tournament_name` = 'SKL Day Tournament'","SELECT `pool_id` FROM `pools` WHERE `pool_name` = 'Pool A'");

this query in inserting 0 in torunament_id and pool_id while record exist in database against SKL Day Tournament and Pool A

can someone suggest is this correct format for mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in original query - SELECTS inside VALUES included in double quotes
it mean You try insert TEXT value into INT column

but in any case, this form of query is not correct

better try this:

```
INSERT INTO teams (team_name, tournament_id, pool_id) 
SELECT 
    'Anis' as team_name, 
    (SELECT tournament_id FROM tournaments WHERE tournament_name = 'SKL Day Tournament' LIMIT 1) as tournament_id, 
    (SELECT pool_id FROM pools WHERE pool_name = 'Pool A' LIMIT 1) as pool_id
```